# before clusterisation, should I remove observations with too few measurements?

Tags: clustering, outliers

I have a very unevenly distributed dataset of 462 twitter users. During the window of observation, some of these users have produced as many as 2000 tweets, while others as few as one.

My end is to clusterize these users according to some measures relative to their tweets.
My question is: should I remove some of these users from the dataset or not?
In particular, would you consider that a minimum number of tweets is necessary to obtain a meaningful clustering?

(The number of tweets produced will not be considered as a variable to perform clustering)

These are a few summary statistics about my dataset:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.0    18.0    60.0   153.0   196.5  2010.0
```

[image: Boxplot of the number of tweets by user. Each point is a user. On the y-axis the number of tweets produced by that user.]

Levels of a 10-fold cut:

```
[1] "(-1.01,202]"         "(202,403]"          
[3] "(403,604]"           "(604,805]"          
[5] "(805,1.01e+03]"      "(1.01e+03,1.21e+03]"
[7] "(1.21e+03,1.41e+03]" "(1.41e+03,1.61e+03]"
[9] "(1.61e+03,1.81e+03]" "(1.81e+03,2.01e+03]"
```

The number of users who have produced the least number of tweets:

```
 14 persons produced 1 tweet
 15 persons produced 2 tweet
  9 persons produced 3 tweet
 13 persons produced 4 tweet
  6 persons produced 5 tweet
  5 persons produced 6 tweet
  5 persons produced 7 tweet
  7 persons produced 8 tweet
  5 persons produced 9 tweet
  6 persons produced 10 tweet
```

[image: Distribution of the number of tweets per user]

Any help appreciated in helping me understand which procedure should be used (and according to which motivation!).
Tell me if more information can be useful to better understand the issue.

Comment: What other information do you have about the users ? If you have other data points per user, why not scale the number of tweets (or bin them if you think that makes more sense) and add that as a variable ? Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I will definetely try and understand if there is a relationship between a cluster of users and the number of tweets produced by the users in that cluster. Still I wonder if building clusters with one-tweet-users is a mistake...

Comment: in the error of cheap computing, I would say the answer is to try it and see if it says anything interesting.  I think that doing some hierarchical clustering to get some idea of the correct k for k clustering, or doing a large number of k clusters is called for. I think one important point in situations like this is that there is no theoretically preferred method.  I would also consider doing a pca on the numerical variables and seeing if that adds anything.  If you think it's worthy, I'll add a few more comments and elevate this to an answer.  Else,  good luck with the hunting !

Comment: Look at the data. Maybe the top tweeting users are spammers, and you need to remove them, too! Don't rely on us to guess - we don't have your data - but experiment.

Comment: Hi aginensky and Anony-Mousse: I see what you mean! So there is no apriori correct or wrong method, I am content with that. If you want to formalize an answer I will accept it.